# Error handling methodology

Tags: python

In C, if I'm not wrong, the `main` function returns 0 if no errors occurred, and something different from 0 if an error occurs.

Is is appropriate to do the same in Python (as long as a function does not have to return any specific value but one to indicate the success/failure); or instead just handle exceptions?

Comment: For a function named `check_blub`/`is_blub` you should return `True` or `False`. Often seen too are functions named `validate_blub`, which commonly throw a ValueError.

Comment: @cdarke Thank you for your comment; but understand that I haven't learned C. :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Python you shouldn't use the return value to indicate an error. You should use Exceptions.

So, either let the exception that fired bubble up, or throw a new one.

```
def check_foo(foo):
    if foo == bar:
        do_something(args)

try:
    check_foo(...)
except SomeError:
    # Oops! Failure!
    something_went_wrong()
else:
    # Yay! Success!
    everything_went_well()
```

In some cases it makes sense to have functions that return a boolean, but that shouldn't be used to indicate *errors*.

This is typically used in routine checks where something may be true or false, and neither is exceptional (i.e. neither is *an error*):

```
def is_foo(foo):
    return foo == "foo"
```

Comment: So instead of including the function return in a condition, as some languages do, I just execute all the code and then handle errors. Have I got it?

Comment: @J.C.Rocamonde Yes. And sometimes, you just have no reasonable thing to do in case an error happens, in that case you just let them bubble up and terminate the interpreter altogether.

Answer (score 2):

No, you shouldn't. Python has other forms of error handling, and if you really want to return a success code true and false is the better way. As a caller you should really be able to assume that everything went as expected, and then you can throw some kind of descriptive error if something went wrong.